# Should I go into a master's program for math?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, advice

I'm currently in my undergrad for math and my school offers an expedited bachelor's to master's program. I liked a lot of my math classes, such as all the calculus ones, a symbolic logic course, discrete structures, and some probability stuff. However, I HATE Linear Algebra and I just can't seem to learn it. I'm taking it right now and so far I have done well, but I have no idea what I am doing at the same time. It's also VERY frustrating. So knowing this, will I make it in the graduate program if I choose to do it? My GPA is also 3.7, but will probably take a beating from Linear.

Side note: I do have trouble retaining information sometimes from previous classes, possibly due to my learning disabilities.

Comment: Linear Algebra appears just about everywhere. I would be concerned if this is a weak area. Have you taken Abstract Algebra or Real Analysis? These are considered the pillar courses in math and are weighted heavily in grad school admissions decisions. I would hold off on making a decision until you get through a semester of algebra and analysis.

Comment: I plan on taking an analysis course next semester. The only problem is, the bachelor's to grad program double counts courses (as in I would take 5000 level courses in place of undergrad ones) so the earlier I decide, the less time it will take to complete my masters.

Comment: Linear algebra is very important and is used in almost every branch of pure or applied math I can think of, so there's no way to avoid that if you want to learn higher math.  You say you are doing well so far, though, so there's no need for panic.

Comment: Yea I'll prob just take it again as an audit to just learn it well.

Comment: Don’t take graduate analysis in lieu of the undergraduate version. One of the primary goals of real analysis is to teach you how to write professional proofs, as well as to grow your mathematical maturity. Graduate analysis (measure theory) assumes the material in undergraduate analysis.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not enjoy learning math then graduate school is going to be frustrating and you are not going to like it.

If the only problem is linear algebra this semester you can drop it and take it later when you have less credit hours and more time to spend on it.

Be honest  with yourself and see what you want to do with your life.  Also make an appointment with your academic advisor to see what does he/she think.

Comment: I do like learning math, but it can be frustrating at times. Honestly though, anything can be frustrating. I can't coast through a degree without finding things frustrating. I'll probably just take it again even if I do well in it. Learning things a second time helps immensely.